# How do I replace year value in a Oracle date value

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given a date of birth, how do I replace the year value with current year value
using PL/SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

Find the number of months between the start of the current year and the start of the year of the date of birth and add that many months:

```sql
SELECT date_of_birth,
       ADD_MONTHS(
         date_of_birth,
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'),
           TRUNC(date_of_birth, 'YY')
         )
       ) AS dob_in_current_year
FROM   table_name;
```

**Sample Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name( date_of_birth ) AS
  SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '1984-02-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '1900-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DATE_OF_BIRTH | DOB_IN_CURRENT_YEAR
> :------------ | :------------------
> 01-JAN-70     | 01-JAN-19          
> 29-FEB-84     | 28-FEB-19          
> 31-DEC-00     | 31-DEC-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c509783638bf77091a2f9b9d1307328)*

---

Or as PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  date_of_birth       DATE := DATE '1984-02-29';
  dob_in_current_year DATE;
BEGIN
  dob_in_current_year := ADD_MONTHS(
                           date_of_birth,
                           MONTHS_BETWEEN(
                             TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'),
                             TRUNC(date_of_birth, 'YY')
                           )
                         );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( dob_in_current_year );
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks man for your response,I will give this a try once I come right will  tick your response